# How do I reverse an integer in MIPS?

Tags: integer, mips, reverse

How do I reverse an integer that a user enters in MIPS? For instance, if the user enters 4352, then it would reverse it to 2534 and output it. The other catch is that if the number is 4200, then the reverse would be 24, no leading zeros.

I have the program loading in the integer and I know how to output it fine. What do I do to reverse it? Normally I would convert it to a string and reverse it that way, but I don't know how to do that in MIPS, and couldn't find much.

I know that I can take the number and mod it by 10 to get the lat digit, and add 0x30 to get the ascii number. But after that I am lost.

Comment: What do you mean by "in MIPS"? Do you mean "in MIPS assembly language"? Or "in C++ compiled on a MIPS machine"? Or something else? =)

Comment: if you have the number as integer (not as a string you can reverse), to "mod" the number by 10 is the only way to "reverse" it; while the number is gt 0, you mod it by 10 and accumulate (add) the result to another reg, that you also will mult by 10 to accomodate the next coming number, if any. "Leading zero" will disappears automatically since 0*10^n + 0 = 0 (according to how you do the loop, you could need to adjust the final result dividing by 10). I've not enough mips live knownledge to write down the code blindly, nor an emulator to try in this moment

Comment: Yes it is MIPS assembly, sorry for leaving that out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This snippet should do it (for non-negative integers):

```
     li $a1, 1234       # $a1 contains input number

     xor $a2, $a2, $a2  # $a2 will hold reverse integer
     li $t1, 10
     beqz $a1, end
loop:
     divu $a1, $t1      # Divide number by 10
     mflo $a1           # $a1 = quotient
     mfhi $t2           # $t2 = reminder
     mul $a2, $a2, $t1  # reverse=reverse*10
     addu $a2, $a2, $t2 #         + reminder    
     bgtz $a1, loop
end: 
     j end              # Here $a2 contains the reversed integer
```

Answer (score 2):

In a pseudo language resembling C, the algorithm could be written as:

```
i = the_number;
r = 0;
while (i > 0)
{
   r = r * 10 + i % 10;
   i = i / 10;
}
```

where % is the mod operator. For the actual MIPS assembly code, read the comment to the question... Though it shouldn't be too hard to translate the pseudocode. Anyway you could write it in C, compile into MIPS and then take a look at how the compiler translated it...